# How to reshape data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set as given below-

```
Timestamp = 22-05-2019 08:40 :Light = 64.00 :Temp_Soil = 20.5625 :Temp_Air = 23.1875 :Soil_Moisture_1 = 756 :Soil_Moisture_2 = 780 :Soil_Moisture_3 = 1002

Timestamp = 22-05-2019 08:42 :Light = 64.00 :Temp_Soil = 20.5625 :Temp_Air = 23.125 :Soil_Moisture_1 = 755 :Soil_Moisture_2 = 782 :Soil_Moisture_3 = 1002
```

And I want to Reshape(rearrange) the dataset to orient header columns like [Timestamp, Light, Temp_Soil, Temp_Air, Soil_Moisture_1, Soil_Moisture_2, Soil_Moisture_3] and their values as the row entry in Python.

Comment: What is the source of this dataset? Is this a text file?

Comment: @SupratimHaldar Yes it is a text file.

Comment: Have you tried reading the file line by line passing each line into a regex to extract your data?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions:

Instead of a "true" input file, I used a string:

```
inp="""Timestamp = 22-05-2019 08:40 :Light = 64.00 :TempSoil = 20.5625 :TempAir = 23.1875 :SoilMoist1 = 756 :SoilMoist2 = 780 :SoilMoist3 = 1002
Timestamp = 22-05-2019 08:42 :Light = 64.00 :TempSoil = 20.5625 :TempAir = 23.125 :SoilMoist1 = 755 :SoilMoist2 = 782 :SoilMoist3 = 1002"""
buf = pd.compat.StringIO(inp)
```

To avoid "folding" of output lines, I shortened field names.

Then let's create the result *DataFrame* and a list of "rows" to append to it.
For now - both of them are empty.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp', 'Light', 'TempSoil', 'TempAir',
    'SoilMoist1', 'SoilMoist2', 'SoilMoist3'])
src = []
```

Below is a loop processing input rows:

```
while True:
    line = buf.readline()
    if not(line):    # EOF
        break
    lst = re.split(r' :', line.rstrip())  # Field list
    if len(lst) < 2: # Skip empty source lines
        continue
    dct = {}         # Source "row" (dictionary)
    for elem in lst: # Process fields
        k, v = re.split(r' = ', elem)
        dct[k] = v   # Add field : value to "row"
    src.append(dct)
```

And the last step is to *append* rows from *src* to *df* :

```
df = df.append(src, ignore_index =True, sort=False)
```

When you *print(df)*, for my test data, you will get:

```
          Timestamp  Light TempSoil  TempAir SoilMoist1 SoilMoist2 SoilMoist3
0  22-05-2019 08:40  64.00  20.5625  23.1875        756        780       1002
1  22-05-2019 08:42  64.00  20.5625   23.125        755        782       1002
```

For now all columns are of *string* type, so you can change the required
columns to either *float* or *int*:

```
df.Light = pd.to_numeric(df.Light)
df.TempSoil = pd.to_numeric(df.TempSoil)
df.TempAir = pd.to_numeric(df.TempAir)
df.SoilMoist1 = pd.to_numeric(df.SoilMoist1)
df.SoilMoist2 = pd.to_numeric(df.SoilMoist2)
df.SoilMoist3 = pd.to_numeric(df.SoilMoist3)
```

Note that *to_numeric()* function is clever enough to recognize the possible
type to convert to, so first 3 columns changed their type to *float64*
and the next 3 to *int64*.

You can check it executing `df.info()`.

One more possible conversion is to change *Timestamp* column
to *DateTime* type:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
```